# Is dotnet restore broken on macos?

Tags: c#, nuget

This has recently just started happening.

```
dotnet --version
5.0.104
```

macOS Big Sur version 11.6

when I run

```
dotnet restore
  Determining projects to restore...
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Windows.Extensions 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Security.Principal.Windows 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Security.Permissions 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Security.Principal.Windows 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Security.Permissions 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Windows.Extensions 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Security.Principal.Windows 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Security.Permissions 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Security.Principal.Windows 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Security.Permissions 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Windows.Extensions 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Windows.Extensions 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Drawing.Common 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Drawing.Common 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Drawing.Common 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Drawing.Common 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Security.AccessControl 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Security.AccessControl 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'System.Security.AccessControl 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Security.AccessControl 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : warning NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
/Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
  Failed to restore /Users/xxx/Work/mvc/mvc.csproj (in 753 ms).
  1 of 2 projects are up-to-date for restore.
```

Is this something broken in nuget?

How do I fix "The repository countersignature validity period has expired."?

Comment: See if anything in this article helps: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/microsoft-author-signing-certificate-update/.  Please post back what you find.  See also https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11178

Comment: I would try updating to a later .NET sdk. Reading this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/net-5-nuget-restore-failures-on-linux-distributions-using-nss-or-ca-certificates/) the certificate check was removed in .NET SDK 5.0.202.

Answer (score 6):

This started happening for me recently as well (on macOS Big Sur 11.5.2, `dotnet --version` 5.0.100). I was seeing error messages like:

> warning NU3028: [...] The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.

> error NU3037: [...] The repository countersignature validity period has expired.

> warning NU3037: [...] The repository countersignature validity period has expired.

Upgrading to the latest version of the .NET SDK fixed it (`dotnet --version` currently shows 5.0.401).

Comment: Let me just say "Thank You" for including the version numbers. So often there are posts that leave out the version numbers and it's unclear if the answer is applicable. THANK YOU @donut.

Comment: @Dev Glad it was able to help you out. I spent WAY too long Googling this one before I came across the actual issue.